# Para que serve a função mysql_store_result()?

Tags: mysql, c++, funções

Olá, eu gostaria de saber qual a real função do método mysql_store_result() dentro da linguagem C++ quando nos estamos trabalhando com banco de dados mysql.

Comment: Está função está obsoleta, deve-se utilizar a função que comece com **mysqli_***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É utilizado para transferir (fetch array) **todos** os resultados da consulta.

`mysqli::store_result()` irá transferir todo o resultado gerado, enquanto, diferentemente de`mysqli::use_result()` irá transferir linha por linha.

Não é recomendado o uso deste comando, pois você estaria carregando tudo de uma vez podendo sobrecarregar o banco de dados. Sem contar ainda, que durante a execução deste comando, alterações no banco de dados não são permitidas.

Comment: Sabe-me dizer onde acho um bom material para referência que esteja em português ensinado mais sobre o uso de MySQL dentro do C++? Pois Infelizmente o unico conteúdo de boa qualidade que achei parece conter funções desatualizadas e que ainda por cima é voltado para a linguagem C e não para C++.

Comment: @Khyser Geralmente a documentação das linguagens de programação e dos SGBD são em inglês, é difícil encontrar em português. Uma sugestão, os mesmos comandos que funcionam no php ao utilizar o mysql, também costumam duncionar em c++, pois em php tem muito mais conteúdo.